# imagick.so, конвертация pdf в tiff

Tags: php, imagick

Использую для конвертации:

```
$im2 = new Imagick("file.pdf");
$im2->setImageFormat("tiff");
$im2->writeImage("file.tiff");
```

Беспокоит 2 момента:
 1. Исходный pdf весит 150 кб, итоговый tiff весит 3.9 Мб
 2. Потеря качества при конвертировании

Не могу найти, как использовать TIFF G4 при конвертации. (итоговый файл будет использоваться для отправки на факс)

Comment: Видимо, исходный файл текстовый? $im2->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_GROUP4);

Comment: @ilyaplot Да, все верно, файл текстовый. Попробовал, сильно потерялось качество.
Попробовал $im2->setImageCompressionQuality(100); и прочие значения, но не помогло.

Comment: TIFF сам по себе тяжелый формат. Текст, преобразованный в изображение никогда не будет выглядеть в первозданном виде.

Comment: @ilyaplot Итоговый результат выглядит вообще нечитаемо.
Видимо, придется использовать другие решения.
Спасибо!